# Need interpretation of functions and pointers

Tags: c

- `((u8_t *)addr)[0]`
- `%02x`
- `((struct uip_udpip_hdr *)&uip_buf[UIP_LLH_LEN])`
- `static struct uip_udp_conn *server_conn`
- `((char *)uip_appdata)[uip_datalen()] = 0;`
- `PRINT6ADDR(&UDP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);`
- `state = uip_ds6_if.addr_list[i].state;`

I need interpretation of the above C lines in simple english.

Comment: Do you usually get other people to do your homework?

Comment: It is not a homework. It is some lines from a contiki example file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very briefly:

```
((u8_t *)addr)[0]
```

First octet of `addr`.

```
%02x
```

This is a format string for the `printf` family of functions.  It will print a hexadecimal number padded to 2 digits (e.g. `5c`).

```
((struct uip_udpip_hdr *)&uip_buf[UIP_LLH_LEN])
```

A `struct uip_udpip_hdr` at the offset `UIP_LLH_LEN` from `uip_buf` in memory.

```
static struct uip_udp_conn *server_conn
```

A static pointer to a `struct uip_udp_conn`, called `server_conn`.

```
((char *)uip_appdata)[uip_datalen()] = 0;
```

Set the char at offset `uip_datalen()` (in chars) from `uip_appdata` to 0.  I'm guessing this is supposed to set a null terminator.

```
PRINT6ADDR(&UDP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);
```

I'm guessing this prints the IPv6 address contained in `UDP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr` ("source IP address").

```
state = uip_ds6_if.addr_list[i].state;
```

Assign `uip_ds6_if.addr_list[i].state` to `state`.  :-)